# Show that there is a minor basis B of V

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $V$ be a vectorspace, $\dim V=k$ and $\phi:V\to V$ an endomorphism. Further, there is a characteristic polynomial $x\phi(x)=\sum_{i=0}a_ix^i$ of $\phi$ irreducible,i.e. $x\phi=fg\implies \deg f=0\;\lor \deg g=0$

Show that there is a minor basis $B$ of $V$:

\begin{equation}
D_{B B}(\Phi)=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
{0} & {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-a_{0}} \\
{1} & {0} & {0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-a_{1}} \\
{0} & {1} & {0} & {0} & {\cdots} & {0} & {-a_{2}} \\
{\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\
{0} & {\cdots} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} & {-a_{n-3}} \\
{0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {-a_{n-2}} \\
{0} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {\cdots} & {0} & {1} & {-a_{n-1}}
\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}
\end{equation}

Comment: Please, see the MathJax tutorial. I don't know a word of German.

Comment: What are your attempts? If you have difficulties with coding, download Snip

Comment: thanks for the help. Unfortunately i have no approach.